# asp.net gridview & sqldatasource only for update mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updates

I have a `gridview` in which the data is bind from a `arraylist` in `page_load` function

```
    Node node = new Node();
    node.buildTree("all", "arraylist");
    al = node.getArrayList();
    GridView2.DataSource = al;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

I want to enable the update mode for this gridview, but I only know using `sqldatasource` to do this. the gridview must use

```
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
```

to link up the datasource. But after I use

```
GridView2.DataSource = al;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

The `gridview` restrict me to use `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`, ask me to remove one defintion.

How do I enable update mode for this grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want use update mode of grid view this link help you
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

but in other way you can use ItemCommand event. In this case you set command for your field 'UpdateCommand' and then in ItemCommand event, check if CommandName is 'UpdateCommand' go to other page for update record.